# Issue with setting a correct work directory in docker container built from Jenkins

Tags: spring, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm trying to get some experience with Docker and Jenkins, and want to deploy a Spring boot server using both of these technologies. But it seems like I specified the actual build incorrectly in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ARG mongoConnection
ARG jwtSecret
ENV MONGODB_CONNECTION=$mongoConnection
ENV JWT_SECRET=$jwtSecret
COPY build/libs/test-server.jar test-server.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "test-server.jar"]
```

When I build the container through Jenkins with the following commands...

```
./gradlew cleanBuild
docker build --build-arg mongoConnection=$MONGODB_CONNECTION --build-arg jwtSecret=$JWT_SECRET -t test-server .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name test-server  test-server
```

...docker does not seem to find the .jar file. How would I set the work directory correctly, so docker is able to deploy the server? Or is my approach completely wrong?

This is the exact error:

> COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder542655905/build/libs/test-server.jar:
>   no such file or directory

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Turns out the .jar file was not created because the ./gradlew cleanBuild command was not correct. Instead it should have been `gradle clean build`. That's what happens when you always only build with IntelliJ...

Comment: Everything after the `docker-builder` directory name is a copy of the path you passed to `docker build` (that is, `.`); does the jar file exist in that path on your local system after you run the Gradle build?

Comment: Try building and running locally to isolate if this is Jenkins related at all. It probably is not though since you are not using any Jenkins plugins.

Comment: Turns out the .jar file was not created because the ./gradlew cleanBuild command was not correct. Thanks for your help!